# add onclick that loads htm page into a div area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to this so excuse my ignorance. I'm working on an image gallery and have added a script to load thumbnails into a div id="loadarea" when mousing over an image link.

I then added a carousel slider to the thumbnail div so I could fit more on thumbs. The carousel slider has a callback called onthumbnailclick that will open the link in a new window, but I would rather it load another div id="imageinfo" with an html page containing detailed image info.

Is this possible. I am very inexperienced with javascript and jquery.

Comment: Yes its possible. Please do some jQuery ajax tutorials, then try to solve the issue yourself, and then post back here with specifics on where you got stuck.

Comment: `$('#imageinfo').load(html_goes_here);`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to load a page into a div using `jQuery` `load` method. You should render only the required markup from this page. You can pass data as well to your page using `load` method.

If you want to do any massaging once the response comes you can do it inside its complete callback handler.

```
$('#imageinfo').load('imgaeInfo.html', { imageId: 1111 },  function() {
    alert('Image info loaded');
});
```

`.load()` referece: http://api.jquery.com/load/

If you want to just get the content from some section of the you can take a look at `Loading Page Fragments` in the jQuery `load` reference.

Comment: Thank you! I know my question is probably extremely basic. It will take me some time to work through your answer, but I can see how it is what I am looking for. And thanks for showing extra options. I'll post back.

Comment: Good that made sense to you, mark it as answer whenever you can.